# serving media files in django with a small size

Tags: django, media

I'm building a `Django` app (call it Drive) to upload photos (2MB or higher) and use its links in another project.

The problem is when uploading all photos on the `drive` and adding their links in the other project
the photos take a lot of time to load, I found a solution to server these photos on the `drive` itself and `compress` them when `uploading`, but still takes a long time to load.

this is the serve function:

```py
def serve(request, path, document_root=None):
    file_link = path
    file = File.objects.get(privacy__link=file_link)
    rendered_file = FileResponse(file.file)
    return rendered_file
```

it returns the file as a `FileResponse` and then it will be returned in its full size and I think that is the problem, and I don't want something like this to happen, I just want to `preview` the photos with small sizes to load faster on the site.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to serve a thumbnail of your image in this view. This is a common scenario and you can find [multiple Django packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/thumbnails/) supporting this in different ways.

[`ImageKit`](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit), for example, introduces a new kind of model field that automatically generates a new version of an existing `ImageField`. You could then simply serve the automatically generated image in your view.

An example, taken from `ImageKit`'s docs:

```py
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
    avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='avatar',
                                      processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 60})
```

Comment: yes, I use these photos as a thumbnail and I think this solution will work perfectly, but I also use them as assets for the website for example website background, section images (png, jpg). what can I do in this case?

Comment: I don't really know your setup so I can just offer a suggestion here: You could introduce another view that serves the original image. By doing so, you could use two URL patterns: one for thumbnails and one for full-scale images.